# Is "The Challenger" achievement broken in Halo 4?

Tags: achievements, halo-4

There is an Halo 4 achievement that reads:

> **The Challenger**
>
> Complete 25 Challenges.

My Spartan record shows 25 challenges complete, but I don't have this achievement.

What am I missing?

Is this achievement broken? If so is there anything I can do to get it to work?

Comment: I don't think it's broken. I achieved it recently, as soon as I hit 25 challenges I got the achievement.

Comment: @Jasarien that doesn't mean that it's not broken - plenty of times there are game breaking glitches that affect some players but not others. It could just mean that you were lucky.

Comment: @Jasarien how do your challenges break down? Are they Campaign, War Games or Spartan Ops?

Comment: A mixture. Mostly wargames. Daily challenges probably make up the most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The achievement isn't "broken" necessarily, as it can still be unlocked.  I unlocked it last night with 27 challenges completed.

Basically, it **may take more than 25** challenges completed to unlock, but it should eventually happen.  I've seen reports of anywhere from **25-50 challenges** completed before it unlocks.  Just keep playing, and you'll be alright.

Here's a link to a forum post discussing the issue: [Xbox.com Halo 4 Challenger Issue](http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_360_games/e_k/halo_4/f/2481/p/393754/1999266.aspx#1999266)

If you do a Google search, you'll find several more websites where people are discussing this.

Comment: I dunno, an achievement that says _"Complete 25 Challenges"_ but actually requires an unknown number between 25 and 50 still sounds like a bug to me. At least (from your description) it should still be attainable. I guess the question becomes: which challenges actually count?

Comment: All of the challenges count, there's just something not right keeping track behind the scenes.  Much like the "Seriously..." achievement in Gears of War 1, people received it at wildly different numbers.  In my mind "broken" means you can't get it, and you definitely can with this achievement.  How many challenges have you completed?

Comment: 25, like I said in the question - I expected to get the achievement either when the challenge popped during the match or at the end of the match. I'll keep going and update this if the achievement pops.

Comment: It popped for me on the 26th challenge. I've no idea what was different about that one.

Answer (score 1):

Anecdotal evidence, but I completed it with only 25 last night.  I tend to complete very few War Games challenges and have focused almost purely on Campaign/Spartan Ops.  They have repeated one or two challenges and I don't know if the achievement is looking for *unique* challenges.

At the end of the day, there are a minimum of 5 extremely easy challenges every week (Spartan Ops) and several other low hanging fruit.  I'd expect in all but the most rare of circumstances you'd have it in another week.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful how you're getting the counts of how many challenges you've completed. If you're not careful, you could be counting them twice. For example, if Waypoint says the following:

- War Games: 7
- Daily: 4
- Spartan Ops: 15
- Weekly: 21
- Campaign: 3
- Monthly: 0

You have completed 25 challenges (4+21+0, or 7+15+3), not 50.